# Tomcat 8.0.33 crashing with Spring security

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-security

I am having issues with tomcat crash every time when load occur on JVM,
    I am getting below error logs initially it is working fine. When some users are increased to access the server then server crashing every time. 
    My java version is 8.0_222 please help me to get out of this issue

Thanks in advance.

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f5e79885cb8, pid=3364, tid=0x00007f5df6fef700
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (8.0_222-b10) (build 1.8.0_222-b10)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.222-b10 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [core.so+0x7cb8]  socket_send+0x98
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.33/bin/hs_err_pid3364.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
Sep 23, 2019 11:55:39 -0700 [5979 1] com.newrelic INFO: New Relic Agent: Loading configuration file "/opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.33/newrelic/./newrelic.yml"
Sep 23, 2019 11:55:40 -0700 [5979 1] com.newrelic INFO: New Relic Agent: Writing to log file: /opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.33/newrelic/logs/newrelic_agent.log
[GC (Allocation Failure) [ParNew: 545344K->35317K(613440K), 0.0337966 secs] 545344K->35317K(5174784K), 0.0338674 secs] [Times: user=0.12 sys=0.01, real=0.04 secs] 
[GC (CMS Initial Mark) [1 CMS-initial-mark: 0K(4561344K)] 35327K(5174784K), 0.0046687 secs] [Times: user=0.01 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
[CMS-concurrent-mark-start]
[CMS-concurrent-mark: 0.001/0.001 secs] [Times: user=0.01 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
[CMS-concurrent-preclean-start]
[CMS-concurrent-preclean: 0.005/0.005 secs] [Times: user=0.03 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs] 
[CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean-start]
23-Sep-2019 11:55:44.925 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.SetAllPropertiesRule.begin [SetAllPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Connector} Setting property 'keepAlivetimeout' to '60000' did not find a matching property.
23-Sep-2019 11:55:44.940 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.SetAllPropertiesRule.begin [SetAllPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Connector} Setting property 'keepAlivetimeout' to '60000' did not find a matching property.
23-Sep-2019 11:55:45.033 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.0.33
23-Sep-2019 11:55:45.033 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Mar 18 2016 20:31:49 UTC
23-Sep-2019 11:55:45.033 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server number:         8.0.33.0
23-Sep-2019 11:55:45.033 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Linux
23-Sep-2019 11:55:45.033 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            3.10.0-957.27.2.el7.x86_64
23-Sep-2019 11:55:45.033 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
23-Sep-2019 11:55:45.033 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.222.b10-0.el7_6.x86_64/jre
23-Sep-2019 11:55:45.034 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.8.0_222-b10
23-Sep-2019 11:55:45.034 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
23-Sep-2019 11:55:45.034 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         /opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.33
23-Sep-2019 11:55:45.034 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         /opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.33
```

Comment: Latest Tomcat 8 is 8.5.46, so you should try upgrading. If you don't want to use Tomcat 8.5, use the latest 8.0, which is 8.0.53, but be aware that Tomcat 8.0.x has reached [end of life](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-80-eol.html).

Comment: Ah good call about upgrading Tomcat.

Answer (score 1):

It's a segmentation fault in native code, and as the first line says, it's a fatal error. Since it's in native code, you don't have a lot of options. I see `com.newrelic` there, and that *could* be relevant here, since the agent can do some tricky things.

Normally the advice would be "use the latest version", but you're using build 1.8.0_222-b10 already, and upgrading to a later major version would probably cause more problems. As Andreas said, you could still see if upgrading Tomcat helps.

If you can run it without the New Relic agent enabled, you could at least see if it's relevant somehow, and take it off the list as a potential problem source.